# Django POST request from a HTML dynamic form

Tags: python, django

I have develop a dynamic form with Bootstrap and Javascript, now I'd like to post that information in sql3 database (default django database), so I made a POST REQUEST in HTML file, views.py and the respective models.py

But when I try to push the submit bottom from the form, nothings happens, I think the issue is how the form was made, but I can't figure out how to solve it.

```
Infraestructura.html

{% extends "Portafolio/layout.html" %}
{% load static %} 

{% block scripts %}
<script src = "{% static 'Portafolio/scriptinfra.js' %}" type="text/javascript"></script>    
{% endblock %}  

{% block content %}

<form action= "{% url 'infraestructura' %}" method="POST" class="form mt-5" id="infra">
  {% csrf_token %}
    <h1>Factibilidad Técnica y Operativa</h1>
    <h2>Análisis de Infraestructura</h2>

    <main class="container">
      <section class="row">

        <div class="col-lg-4 mb-2">
          <input name='Infraestructura' class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="Infraestructura">
        </div>

        <div class="col-lg-4 mb-2">
          <input name='Tiempo' class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="Tiempo">
        </div>

        <div class="col-lg-4 mb-2">
          <input name='Costo' class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="Costo Mensual">
        </div>      
      </section>

    </main>

    <nav class="btn-group">
      <button id='add' class='btn btn-success' type='button'>
        <i class="fa fa-plus-square"></i> Añadir
      </button>
      <button id='rem' class='btn btn-danger' type='button'>
        <i class="fa fa-minus-square"></i> Eliminar
      </button>     
    </nav>
    <!-- Submit buttom-->
        <div class="d-grid gap-2 mt-3">
          <input type="submit" class="btn btn-lg btn-primary">
        </div>
  </form>
  
{% endblock %}

views.py

def infraestructura(request):
    if request.method =='POST':
        Infraestructura = request.POST.get('Infraestructura')
        Tiempo = request.POST.get('Tiempo')
        Costo = request.POST.get('Costo')

        Infraestructura.objects.create(Infraestructura=Infraestructura, Tiempo=Tiempo, Costo=Costo)
        
    return render (request, "Portafolio/Infraestructura.html")

models.py

class Infraestructura(models.Model):
    Infraestructura= models.CharField(max_length= 64)
    Tiempo = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True)
    Costo = models.BigIntegerField(null=True, blank=True)
```

** UPDATE 1**

scriptinfra.js

```
window.onload = function(){
  const ui = document.forms.infra;
  const io = ui.elements;

  ui.onclick = addRem;

function addRem(event) {
  const clicked = event.target;
  const main = document.querySelector('.container');
  let rows = main.querySelectorAll('.row');
  
  if (clicked.matches('#add')) {
    const row = ` <section class="row"><div class="col-lg-4 mb-2"> <input name='Infraestructura' class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="Infraestructura"> </div> <div class="col-lg-4 mb-2"> <input name='Tiempo' class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="Tiempo"> </div> <div class="col-lg-4 mb-2"> <input name='Costo' class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="Costo Mensual"> </div> </section>`;
    main.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeEnd', row);
  } else if (clicked.matches('#rem') && rows.length > 1) {
    rows[rows.length-1].remove();
  } else {
    return false;
  }
}; 
}
```

Comment: Try printing the post data and check whether it can be seen in console

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your views.py you have reused `Infraestructura`, so it no longer represents a model class. You can avoid this by using lowercase variable names.

Try this instead:

```py
def infraestructura(request):
    if request.method =='POST':
        infraestructura = request.POST.get('Infraestructura')
        tiempo = request.POST.get('Tiempo')
        costo = request.POST.get('Costo')

        Infraestructura.objects.create(Infraestructura=infraestructura, Tiempo=tiempo, Costo=costo)
        
    return render (request, "Portafolio/Infraestructura.html")
```

Take a look at the [Django coding style](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/internals/contributing/writing-code/coding-style/#model-style) for best practices.

**Update**

Now that you have added your `scriptinfra.js` code, we can see the problem.

When you click on anything in the form, the `addRem` function is called. If you click anything that doesn't match either of your rules, the function returns `false`. When this happens, links won't work and forms won't submit.

Remove the `else` and `return false` and see how you go.

Comment: I made the changed, but it still don't do nothing. I'll give you more information.

 I remember when I was creating this form I had problems to create <a> tag (href didn't do nothing), I resolve it putting the <a> tags outside the <form> tags, but in this case I really need that submit buttom remains inside the form to make POST REQUEST.

Comment: @Thrillidas Just so I understand, what do you expect it to do when you submit the form?

Comment: Send the data into default Django database

Comment: @Thrillidas OK. If the form won't submit, your javascript may be interfering. Can you update the question with the content of `Portafolio/scriptinfra.js` and any other custom javascript you are using?

Comment: It works! thanks a lot !, I'm new in javascript, but thanks to you I have learnt a little bit ! Have a nice day !